# Telerik RadControls RadFormDecorator - Tow Problem About Positioning

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, visual-studio-2008-sp1

i am using asp.net with c# web app in vs 2008

problem 1:

i do not know why Telerik RadControls- RadFormDecorator Moves some controls (such as Buttons or chech boxes) and changes their positioning up or down in my form after viewing in browser...

i put those controls in a cell of a table ... but not help

i had this problem about radajaxmanager and by setting UpdatePanelsRenderMode property to inline problem solved - but here there is no property like that...
what is going on here?

problem2:
i decorated my buttons and chechboxes with radformdecorator (telerik radcontrols) control...
when i click on a checkbox to set it to true or false so my webpage positioning goes to up (like when postback occurs , but this is not postback)
how can i prevent this problem ?

thanks for attention

Comment: I Found The Reason Of Problem 1:

when i set the direction of body to rtl my page moves vertically and goes up when vertical scroll bar is enabled...

when i remove that dir from body (default = ltr) my page moves horizontally and goes to left when horizontal scroll bar is active

Comment: i correct comment #1 by me - that was about problem 2

Comment: any body home?
i was checking this thread every day without any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens in some scenarios because of the way RadFormDecorator styles checkboxes - real checkboxes are hidden outside of the viewport. When the decorated checkbox is clicked however, browsers try to focus the real checkbox, hence the "jumping". To avoid that, you should set **position:relative** to the parent container.